# Root element in html method

Tags: jquery, html, xml

In jQuery `.html()` method somehow do not return root element, for example:

```
var test = $('<root><val>hello world</val></root>');
var str = test.html(); // '<val>hello world</val>'
```

how can i get string with root tag included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html). Short answer: `clone()` the element, `wrap()` it, and call `html()` on the result.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `outerHTML` property. Firefox doesn't support it, so you'll need to include a fix:

```
var str = test[0].outerHTML || $('<div>').append(test).html();
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ub244/

Comment: Comparing your rep to mine, I'm clearly not in a position to advise you on etiquette, but do note that this is a clear duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: well, not EXACTLY. Explaining why this is happening only leads to the other question.

Comment: @Phrogz: The solutions posted in that duplicate don't utilize the `outerHTML` property. Anyway, most questions on SO these days seem to be dupes. If others want to close it, they may.

Comment: will `test[0].outerHTML` ever not be `true`? Would that return `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: @hunter: In Firefox, it will be `undefined` ("falsey") because the property simply doesn't exist. As such, it will utilize the append method.

Answer (score 1):

because `test` **IS** the `<root>` element. You're creating it and selecting it.

`html()` will return the `innerHTML` for the element selected, which in this case is `<root>`

---

what you're looking for is the `outerHtml`.

See this question: [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html)

---

You can get the root from the jQuery object and then call get it's outer html like so:

```
test.get(0).outerHTML;
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U7Zdc/

Answer (score 0):

That's intended functionality.  The docs for .html() state:

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

So, the variable `test` is a jQuery object pointing to the `<root>` element. Calling .html() on it will return HTML *within* the element. It's the same as using plain JavaScript's *innerHTML* propery.

To get `<root>` as well, you need to wrap `test` with another element and get the contents of it:
`$('<div>').append(test.clone()).remove().html();`

Comment: so there is no way to get full string?